# Is there a way to instruct \includepdf to carry-on if no file present?

Tags: pdfpages

Is there a way to instruct `\includepdf` to carry-on if no file present?

It occurs to me that this could be done via an option, or by wrapping the `\includepdf` command in an `if` statement which leverages some filesystem query.

Comment: `\IfFileExists{some.pdf}{true}{false}`

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be [an option in `includepdf`](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf), but if you want to redefine `\includepdf` to behave this way, you can use code like this (assuming you always provide an optional argument):

```latex
\let\realincludepdf=\includepdf
\def\includepdf[#1]#2{\IfFileExists{#2}
  {\realincludepdf[#1]{#2}}
  {\fbox{Missing #2}}}
```